# How do I write this line without errors?

Tags: php

My code has to be:

```
$name = 'Pete';
$name2 = 'Jones';
$data = "$x['$name'] = '$name2';";
```

$x 
shouldn't be changed to the value of $x, but just remain $x. $name, does have to change to Pete and $name2 has to change to Jones. How can I write the line $data without having errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Am not sure what exactly you want to achive .. what would be the final Result of `$data` ???

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand what you're trying to do without context. What is `$data` meant to look like when displayed/var_dumped?

Comment: it should be $x['Pete'] = 'Jones';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `$`:

```
$data = "\$x['$name'] = '$name2'";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.